# Symfony return me a "syntax error or access violation"

Tags: symfony

all are in the subject, i not find syntax error, can you help me ?

```
INSERT INTO user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, firstname, lastname, key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["foo", "foo", "foo@bar.com", "foo@bar.com", 0, "salt", "password", null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:0:{}", 0, null, "data", "data", "apikey"]
```

This request is performed by the basic persist entity of Symfony Doctrine

Regards

Comment: Since you did not show the exact error, which would help a lot, I will shoot in the dark. At first glance I can see that you're having a column named `key`, and this is a reserved word. Either change it to something else or paste the whole error here so we can se exactly where your query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `key` column to something else. By the way, it doesn't work, if do it in Entity class. First of all, you need to rename the column in DB manually.